# Getting extra <b> tag in output

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I am using codeigniter v 3.x

Now I make a function to load viewes with templates

```
    function load_guest($view,$data=array('data'=>''),$headerdata=array('data'=>''),$PageTitle='',$PageKeywords='',$PageDescription=''){
        $CI = & get_instance();  //get instance, access the CI superobject
        $headerdata['title']=$PageTitle;
        $headerdata['keyword']=$PageKeywords;
        $headerdata['description']=$PageDescription;
        $CI->load->view('partial/head',$headerdata);
        //Here i am getting opening <b> tag on html output
        $CI->load->view($view,$data);
        //Here i am getting closing </b> tag on html output
        $CI->load->view('partial/foot');
    }
```

But when I see the html source after loading any page on browser. I see a pair of `<b></b>` tag into the source.

I checked my whole project and search for `<b>` tag and I am sure I am not using `<b>` tag anywhere.

I use Phpstorm so I find in path for `<b>` tag and nothing found...

***EDIT***
I am using a hook also

```
function compress()
{

    ini_set("pcre.recursion_limit", "16777");
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $buffer = $CI->output->get_output();
    $re = '%# Collapse whitespace everywhere but in blacklisted elements.
        (?>             # Match all whitespans other than single space.
          [^\S ]\s*     # Either one [\t\r\n\f\v] and zero or more ws,
        | \s{2,}        # or two or more consecutive-any-whitespace.
        ) # Note: The remaining regex consumes no text at all...
        (?=             # Ensure we are not in a blacklist tag.
          [^<]*+        # Either zero or more non-"<" {normal*}
          (?:           # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct
            <           # or a < starting a non-blacklist tag.
            (?!/?(?:textarea|pre|script)\b)
            [^<]*+      # more non-"<" {normal*}
          )*+           # Finish "unrolling-the-loop"
          (?:           # Begin alternation group.
            <           # Either a blacklist start tag.
            (?>textarea|pre|script)\b
          | \z          # or end of file.
          )             # End alternation group.
        )  # If we made it here, we are not in a blacklist tag.
        %Six';

    $new_buffer = preg_replace($re, " ", $buffer);
      // We are going to check if processing has working
    if ($new_buffer === null)
    {
        $new_buffer = $buffer;
    }

    $CI->output->set_output($new_buffer);
    $CI->output->_display();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my broken English...

Comment: What about views files "partial/foot", "partial/head" and  $view?

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy They are just Html files for my template(partial/head and partial/foot) and $view is the main view to load.

Comment: yes, those files will throw html too

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to solve this problem using a lazy trick.

In hook compress() function I replace all `<br>` tag manually.

```
$new_buffer = str_replace("<b>","",$new_buffer);
$new_buffer = str_replace("</b>","",$new_buffer);
$new_buffer = str_replace("</ b>","",$new_buffer);
```

This partially solves my problem. But I still want to know, is there a better solution for this?